# Reinstall an existing Module using Composer (in Git)

Tags: composer, versioning

I have a module already installed in the tree and want to replace it by installation via composer.

The magento hackathon composer installed is used.

Also all symlinks created by the installer are excluded via .gitignore

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- First `git rm` to remove all existing parts of the module and then `git commit`
- This could also partially be done by adding the module first and use the magento-force option which would already delete most of the files - but this needs some fine tuning using `git rm` / unstaging

  - Now add the module and make the git commit, add the symlinks to the `.gitignore`
  - push your changes to the git repository

When the co-developers do an update, in the first step git will delete the old module and then install the new module (after composer update). From this part on, the symlinks are ignored.

Comment: Nice question (and answer) ;)
The workflow with modman nearly conforms this way.
What is really important, is to do a commit after deleting the files, otherwise there will be conflicts in the other developers working-copies later.